# Can somone explain this specific Summary Notation to me?

Tags: summation

Been re-teaching myself all the math I slept through in high school. Really enjoying the challenge, but I hit a wall last night. The workbook I have has the following notation:

$$\prod_{i=0}^4 7(i + 1)$$

To me, this meant:$( 7\cdot(0 + 1) ) \cdot ( 7 \cdot(1+1) ) $ etc., or $7 \cdot 14 \cdot 21 \cdot 28$, or $153664$.

The answer in the book is $2016840$ - So, obviously I'm missing something. I've looked at other websites, but I can't find the thing that I'm not understanding. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Your understanding is correct. You just missed the last term in your calculation. There is a *35 in the end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are interpreting the symbol correctly, you're just making a mistake with the calculation. I'm not sure where you're getting $153664$ from, but it's probably an arithmetic mistake.

The "$4$" is inclusive, so the last term in the multiplication is $7\cdot 5$. Indeed, we can rearrange the product to get
$$\prod_{i=0}^47(i+1)=[7(0+1)][7(1+1)]\cdots[7(4+1)]=7^5\cdot 5!$$ since there are five factors of $7$, and the rest is just the product of numbers from $1$ to $5$. Computing $7^5\cdot 5!$ gives the book's answer.

Comment: Thanks so much- I somehow forgot the 4 was inclusive and I also have no idea where I pulled 153,664 from. Always eat breakfast before you start working!

Comment: Yeah, when I realized it wasn't a factor of the answer I just decided that you had pressed the wrong buttons on a calculator or something

Comment: I was puzzled by that, too. I'm in that weird trough where I feel like I don't know enough to know what I know!